# Modals issue discord

Tags: discord, discord.js

So I'm trying to get all information that the bot gets within the ticket setup and it just gives me a error with trying to get everything from the model and no errors in console.

[image: the error in discord]

I hope someone had this before and can help me with this because its a project that needs to be done in 2 days.

This is the code I used:
(I know my code is messy, I'm sorry for that)

```js
const { Client, Intents, MessageActionRow, MessageSelectMenu, MessageEmbed, Modal, TextInputComponent } = require('discord.js');

const CHEATER_REPORT_CATEGORY_ID = '1168652985249845321';
const SERVER_ISSUES_CATEGORY_ID = '1168653034058956810';
const DONATIONS_CATEGORY_ID = '1179062044767567924';

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.MESSAGE_CONTENT,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
  ],
});

const ticketOptions = [
  { label: 'Cheater Report', value: 'cheater_report', category: CHEATER_REPORT_CATEGORY_ID },
  { label: 'Server Issues', value: 'server_issues', category: SERVER_ISSUES_CATEGORY_ID },
  { label: 'Donations', value: 'donations', category: DONATIONS_CATEGORY_ID },
];

// Sample list of server names
const serverNames = ['SoloDuo1', 'SoloDuo2', '4Man1', '4Man2', '6Man1', '8Man1'];

const ticketDropdown = new MessageActionRow()
  .addComponents(
    new MessageSelectMenu()
      .setCustomId('ticketDropdown')
      .setPlaceholder('Select the type of ticket')
      .addOptions(ticketOptions.map(option => ({
        label: option.label,
        value: option.value,
      })))
  );

const serverDropdown = new MessageActionRow()
  .addComponents(
    new MessageSelectMenu()
      .setCustomId('serverDropdown')
      .setPlaceholder('Select the server')
      .addOptions(serverNames.map(server => ({
        label: server,
        value: server.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '_'),
      })))
  );

client.once('ready', () => {
  const ticketChannel = client.channels.cache.get('1146563285190197378');
  if (ticketChannel) {
    ticketChannel.send({
      content: 'To open a ticket, please select the type of issue:',
      components: [ticketDropdown],
    });
  } else {
    console.error('Unable to find the specified ticket channel.');
  }
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
  if (!interaction.isSelectMenu()) return;

  if (interaction.customId === 'ticketDropdown') {
    const selectedValue = interaction.values[0];
    const selectedOption = ticketOptions.find(option => option.value === selectedValue);


    // Create the ticket channel in the specified category
    const ticketCategoryID = selectedOption.category;
    const ticketChannel = await interaction.guild.channels.create(
      `${selectedValue}-1`,
      {
        type: 'GUILD_TEXT',
        parent: ticketCategoryID,
      }
    );

    // Send the server name dropdown in the ticket channel
    if (selectedValue === 'donations' || selectedValue === 'server_issues' || selectedValue === 'cheater_report') {
      await ticketChannel.send({
        content: `Ticket type selected: ${selectedOption.label}\nPlease provide the following information:`,
        components: [serverDropdown],
      });

      // Wait for the user to respond to the server dropdown
      const serverDropdownFilter = (interaction) => {
        return interaction.customId === 'serverDropdown' && interaction.user.id;
      };

      const serverDropdownCollector = ticketChannel.createMessageComponentCollector({
        filter: serverDropdownFilter,
      });

      serverDropdownCollector.on('collect', async (interaction) => {



      if (selectedValue === 'cheater_report') {
        const modal = new Modal()
          .setCustomId('myModal')
          .setTitle('Additional Information');

        // Add components to modal (text inputs, etc.)
        const cheatername = new TextInputComponent()
          .setCustomId('cheaterName')
          .setLabel("Enter cheater\'s in-game name")
          .setStyle('SHORT');

        const evidence = new TextInputComponent()
          .setCustomId('cheaterEvidence')
          .setLabel("Enter evidence and details of cheating")
          .setStyle('PARAGRAPH');

        const firstActionRow = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(cheatername);
        const secondActionRow = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(evidence);
 
        modal.addComponents(firstActionRow, secondActionRow);

        // Show the modal to the user
        await interaction.showModal(modal);
      if (!interaction.isModalSubmit()) return;
        // Close the modal
        if (!interaction.deferred && !interaction.replied) {
  await interaction.isModalSubmit({ content: 'Your submission was received successfully!' });
}
      }


 

  // Get the data entered by the user
  const cheaterName = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('cheaterName');
  const cheaterEvidence = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('cheaterEvidence');

  
  const cheaterNames = cheaterName || 'N/A';
  const cheaterEvidences = cheaterEvidence || 'N/A';
  
        // Create the embed with all information
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle('Ticket Information')
          .addField('Ticket Type', selectedOption.label)
          .addField('Server Name', interaction.values[0])
          .addField('Cheater Name', cheaterNames)
          .addField('Cheater Evidence', cheaterEvidences)
          .setColor('#00FF00'); // You can customize the color

        // Send the embed to ticketChannel
        await ticketChannel.send(embed);

        // Stop the collector to prevent further interactions
        serverDropdownCollector.stop();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Consider making a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code. Not only will this help others understand the code on SO, it might also help you discover the problem on your own. Less code means it's easier to find the spot with the problem :)